# Turtle-saving image but not in eps file

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have a simple program in which you can draw using module Turtle and I want to save what the user has drawn but not in `eps` file rather an `svg` file or `png` file
I tried using this but this gies you the eps file which I dont want

```
ts = k.getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file= name + '.eps')
```

And then I tried using SvgTurtle module but you lose a lot of good functions and it doesnt save things properly for some reason it saves it differently

```
t.save_as(f'{name}.svg')
```

How it should look
[image: How it should look]

How it looks using svgTurtle module and `save_as()`

[image: How it looks using svgTurtle module and save_as()]
the size of the picture is irelevant

here is most of the code:

```
import turtle
from tkinter import colorchooser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
from svg_turtle import SvgTurtle
from tkinter import *
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

t = SvgTurtle(500, 500)

k = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Motýľ")
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(1)

k.speed(0)
k.shape("square")
k.color("red")
k.shapesize(0.3,0.3)
k.pencolor("black")



# Function
def k_up():
    y = k.ycor()
    y += 20
    k.sety(y)
    t.sety(y)
    #print(y)
    #if k.ycor() > 295:
       # k.sety(295)
def k_down():
    y = k.ycor()
    y -= 20
    k.sety(y)
    t.sety(y)


def k_right():
    x = k.xcor()
    x += 20
    k.setx(x)
    t.setx(x)

def k_left():
    x = k.xcor()
    x -= 20
    k.setx(x)
    t.setx(x)
class myGlobal:
    t = 0
    n = 1
def pensizeUp():
    myGlobal.t += 1
    k.pensize(myGlobal.t)
    t.pensize(myGlobal.t)
    if myGlobal.t <=1:
        myGlobal.t += 1
def pensizeDown():
    myGlobal.t -= 1
    k.pensize(myGlobal.t)
    t.pensize(myGlobal.t)
    if myGlobal.t <=1:
        myGlobal.t += 1
    
def pencolor():
    colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser")
    k.pencolor(colors[1])
    k.color(colors[1],'black')
    t.pencolor(colors[1])
    t.color(colors[1],'black')

def dragging(x, y):
    k.ondrag(None)
    t.ondrag(None)
    k.setheading(k.towards(x,y))
    t.setheading(t.towards(x,y))
    k.goto(x,y)
    t.goto(x,y)
    k.ondrag(dragging)
    t.ondrag(dragging)
def clickright(x,y):
    k.clear()
def download():
    k.hideturtle()
    ts = k.getscreen()
    print(ts)
    name = input('napíš názov: ')
    ts.getcanvas().postscript(file= name + '.eps')
    print(ts)
    print('done \n go to this link:  https://cloudconvert.com/eps-to-png  and convert your .eps file to a png for free')
    t.save_as(f'{name}.svg')
    k.showturtle()
def main():
    turtle.listen()
    k.ondrag(dragging)
    turtle.onscreenclick(clickright, 3)
main()
# Binds
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(k_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(k_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(k_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(k_right, "d")

wn.onkeypress(pencolor, "r")

wn.onkeypress(pensizeUp, "Shift_L")
wn.onkeypress(pensizeDown, "Control_L")
wn.onkeypress(download, "l")
#wn.exitonclick()

while True:
    wn.update()
    # Border cheking
    if k.ycor() > 295:
        y = k.ycor()
        if y > 295:
            y = 295
        k.sety(295) 
    if k.ycor() < -288:
        k.sety(-288)
    if k.xcor() > 388:
        k.setx(388)   
    if k.xcor() < -395:
        k.setx(-395)
```